# How to AddDriver the rotation value of the armature for the rotation value of the object

Tags: rigging

I did AddDriver for RotationX of the cube.

From the EditDriver, I selected Armature in Prop.

[image]

In Path, "pose.bones [" Bone "]. Rotation_quaternion [0]" was input.

However, rotating the armature did not move the Cube.

How to AddDriver the rotation value of the armature for the rotation value of the object?

I don't want to use Child of constraints.

Because I want to use Bone's local value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the drivers editor, variable tab, instead of "single property" use "transform channel" ( (X) Symbol), then choose your bone, choose X rotation with auto euler option, choose world or local space, and when rotating the bone in pose mode, X rotation of the cube will follow.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Pose bones belong to the object...**

*[Agree with other answer could use transform channel in driver](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/162951/15543), or a copy rotation constraint.*

Fix for scripted expression as attempted in question

[image]
*No longer red so ...good to go.... oops z component of quatrot*

Two things at play here..

Firstly fix up the datapath, remove spaces and it's all lower case for properties. eg  `rotation_quaternion`  The components of a 4d vector are `wxyz`  IMO using `rotation_quaternion.w` looks better, but it doesn't mather. The correct path for w quat rot of pose bone "Bone" is

Either

```
pose.bones["Bone"].rotation_quaternion.w
```

or

```
pose.bones["Bone"].rotation_quaternion[0]
```

Pose bones belong to the armature object.  Check with the armature object selected in the python console.

```
>>> C.object
bpy.data.objects['Armature']

>>> C.object.pose.bones["Bone"].rotation_quaternion.w
0.7493351101875305
```

For  driver variable target, instead of the object you have selected its armature, the data part of the armature object, notice it is in `bpy.data.armatures` not `bpy.data.objects`.  This is the data that contains the edit bones.

```
>>> C.object.data
bpy.data.armatures['Armature']
```

and has no `pose.bones` collection

```
>>> C.object.data.pose.bones["Bone"].rotation_quaternion.w
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Armature' object has no attribute 'pose'
```

**Via Constraint**

As a copy rotation constraint, like transform channel rotation drivers offers Euler rotations.

[image]
*Constrain local space x rot to local space X rot of bone*